# Как сделать ListBox такого вида в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать ListBox такого вида в WPF?

Начальное состояние:

[image: начальное состояние]

При наведении мышки:

[image: при наведении мышки]

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnter1">
                <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="{x:Null}">
                    <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="134,67,0,67"/>
                    <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="120,55,-12,55"/>
                </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnMouseEnter1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseEnter1}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave">
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="OnMouseEnter1_BeginStoryboard"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="PathStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
        <Setter Property="Data" Value="F1 M 27.5314,21.8628L 33.0126,19.4224L 34.7616,23.3507C 36.6693,22.9269 38.6044,22.8903 40.4668,23.2026L 42.0083,19.1868L 47.6098,21.337L 46.0683,25.3528C 47.6612,26.3669 49.0747,27.6889 50.2088,29.2803L 54.1371,27.5313L 56.5776,33.0126L 52.6493,34.7616C 53.0731,36.6693 53.1097,38.6043 52.7974,40.4668L 56.8131,42.0083L 54.6629,47.6097L 50.6472,46.0683C 49.6331,47.6613 48.3111,49.0748 46.7197,50.2089L 48.4686,54.1372L 42.9874,56.5776L 41.2384,52.6493C 39.3307,53.0731 37.3957,53.1097 35.5333,52.7974L 33.9918,56.8131L 28.3903,54.6629L 29.9318,50.6472C 28.3388,49.6331 26.9252,48.3111 25.7911,46.7196L 21.8628,48.4686L 19.4224,42.9873L 23.3507,41.2383C 22.9269,39.3307 22.8903,37.3957 23.2026,35.5332L 19.1869,33.9918L 21.3371,28.3903L 25.3528,29.9318C 26.3669,28.3388 27.6889,26.9252 29.2804,25.7911L 27.5314,21.8628 Z M 34.3394,29.7781C 29.7985,31.7998 27.7564,37.1198 29.7781,41.6606C 31.7998,46.2015 37.1198,48.2436 41.6606,46.2219C 46.2015,44.2002 48.2436,38.8802 46.2219,34.3394C 44.2002,29.7985 38.8802,27.7564 34.3394,29.7781 Z "/>
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#CC000000"/>
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill"/>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid Margin="50,67,295,80">
        <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Margin="15">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Lamborghini Huracan Green.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
        <Grid Style="{DynamicResource GridStyle1}" Margin="134,67,0,67" Background="#00000000">
            <Ellipse Fill="#9923FF00"/>
            <Path Margin="7" Style="{DynamicResource PathStyle1}"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Margin="124,124,10,10" Background="#00000000">
            <Ellipse Fill="#4C23FF00"/>
            <Path Style="{DynamicResource PathStyle1}" Margin="7" Fill="#99000000"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Margin="124,10,10,124" Background="#00000000">
            <Ellipse Fill="#4C23FF00"/>
            <Path Style="{DynamicResource PathStyle1}" Margin="7" Fill="#99000000"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Margin="85,148,63,0" Background="#00000000">
            <Ellipse Fill="#2623FF00"/>
            <Path Style="{DynamicResource PathStyle1}" Margin="4" Fill="#4C000000"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Margin="85,0,63,148" Background="#00000000">
            <Ellipse Fill="#2623FF00"/>
            <Path Style="{DynamicResource PathStyle1}" Margin="4" Fill="#4C000000"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: А как вы пробовали начать делать это?

Comment: @АндрейNOP С помощью Ellipse, но тогда не удобно добавлять элементы в меню по необходимости + масштабирование кривое получилось

Comment: Показывайте разметку

Comment: Я не представляю как задать в ListBox прокрутку элементов по дуге (по периметру большого круга с картинкой)

Comment: @i4el0vek: Как-как, нужно вычислять координаты по индексу элемента через синус и косинус. По идее, вам нужен контейнер наподобие StackPanel, но размещающий по кругу. Я напишу завтра, если никто не успеет до меня.

Answer (score 0):

Данного поведения с помощью мыши проще всего добиться используя ScaleTransform. Добавьте в стиль контейнера следующее:

```
<Style.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
          <Setter.Value>
             <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Вам не понадобятся ваши ресурсы стиля грида и StoryBoard. Однако, скорее всего данное поведение не будет применимо к контейнеру типа Grid. В таком случае оберните Grid-ы в ContentControl-ы, а указанный выше триггер добавьте в стиль ContentControl. Так все должно сработать.